# Copy and pasting all values from one sheet to another

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro that creates a sheet full of data. I recently added new sheets so that unique values can go into each one. For example if a row contains "Pole Change Out" then that entire row is copy and pasted into the "Pole Change Out" sheet. there are 4 different sheets. My problem is, since some values are determined by a formula in vba, some values are not moving into the new sheet.

```
Sub copy_paste_based_on_cell_interior_rgb()
Dim LastRow As Long

Dim i As Long, j As Long

'Find the last used row in a Column: column A in this example
 With Worksheets("Make-Ready")
  LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
 End With

'first row number where you need to paste values in Sheet1'
With Worksheets("Pole Change Out")
  j = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
End With

For i = 1 To LastRow
   With Worksheets("Make-Ready")
       If .Cells(i, 27).Value = "Pole Change-Out" Then
           .Rows(i).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Pole Change Out").Range("A" & j)
           j = j + 1
       ElseIf .Cells(i, 27).Value = "New Midspan Pole" Then
           .Rows(i).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Midspan Poles").Range("A" & j)
           j = j + 1
       ElseIf .Cells(i, 104).Value = "Yes" Then
           .Rows(i).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Anchor Replacement").Range("A" & j)
           j = j + 1
       End If
   End With
   Next i

   End Sub
```

[image: Current Output]
[image: What It is in "Make-Ready" that needs to be replicated in "Pole Change Out"]

Comment: because you set `j` based on one sheet and add one to it no matter to what sheet it is pasted, you will get blank lines on all the sheets.

Comment: I attached my current results in the question @ScottCraner

Comment: While those are pretty pictures they do not mean anything to us without some more context.  what is wrong with those pictures?

Comment: In your code, j is the row number of a blank row on "Pole Change Out." I think the code needs different variables for the other sheets, "Midspan Poles" and "Anchor Replacement."

Comment: In your ScreenCaptures of "Make-Ready" sheet, there is no "Pole Change-Out", "New Midspan Poles" or "Yes" value, so, what it is supposed that you are expecting from this loop? If it can not find the value, it can not copy it.

Answer (score 0):

As @scottCraner and the others pointed out. You are trying to use the first empty cell variable from one sheet on the other two sheets. The update to your code will automatically update the first blank cell for each sheet.

```
Sub copy_paste_based_on_cell_interior_rgb()
Dim LastRow As Long

Dim i As Long ', j As Long

'Find the last used row in a Column: column A in this example
 With Worksheets("Make-Ready")
  LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
 End With

'first row number where you need to paste values in Sheet1'
'With Worksheets("Pole Change Out")
'  j = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
'End With

For i = 1 To LastRow
   With Worksheets("Make-Ready")
       If .Cells(i, 27).Value = "Pole Change-Out" Then
           .Rows(i).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Pole Change Out").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1)

           'j = j + 1
       ElseIf .Cells(i, 27).Value = "New Midspan Pole" Then
           .Rows(i).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Midspan Poles").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1)

           'j = j + 1
       ElseIf .Cells(i, 104).Value = "Yes" Then
           .Rows(i).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Anchor Replacement").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1)

           'j = j + 1
       End If
   End With
   Next i

   End Sub
```